# protect_from_forgery error but project does run

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, aptana

The new project I created seems to run (showing "Welcome aboard" message) but why is Aptana IDE says there's an error with this line? this is an auto-generated code.

[image]

**Update**
@Grych made me understand the problem is with the IDE, although I've looked at: `Preferences > Ruby > Installed Interpreters` and validated it uses `Ruby200-x64` as desired.

Is there anything else to configure?

Answer (score 2):

This code is OK. It is auto-generated indeed - this will automatically include security token to all rails-generated form.

This colon syntax:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

is an equivalent to:

```
protect_from_forgery :with => :exception
```

The problem is probably in your IDE. Check if you can set up the correct Ruby version somewhere in Aptana IDE.

Comment: It uses `C:\Ruby200-x64` which I installed recently and it's latest for my understanding.